# Stream live website feed on Android

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, live, television

I want to get an idea of how to stream a live feed from a website to a Android Application, do I need to implement on specific framework for streaming? I have the web url for live streaming and its working on web, I want to stream the same feed on Android Application I create.

I guess it will work only on version 2.2 and onward, but need guidelines on how to start it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can stream the website using the Vitamio framework's VideoView.

You would need the streaming URL for the particular feed. ( it might be in playlist format which will have the links inside them / it might be a rtsp/mms streaming).

Please refer to the sample app from Vitamio for the same. https://github.com/yixia

Comment: it is in rtmp format. I downloaded the Vitamio demo and bundle, integrated both of them but they not working :(

Comment: Can you tell me what is not working? Can you provide the FEED URL? I have the setup and can test.

Comment: but the app without using the link is giving issue, if you have working code of that Vitamio Demo, share it please. The app is crashing.